# In the UK, can a private limited company have as its only shareholder a juridical person?

Tags: england-and-wales

The reason I'm asking is that a bank refused to open a business current account for us upon me divulging the information in the title during the application process. In addition, the juridical person is a company based outside the UK, if that could possibly matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes

Companies can own companies - that’s what subsidiaries are.

On a practical level, you know this is true because you actually have an example. Companies House would not have allowed its registration (barring error) if it was illegal.

### Why can’t it open a bank account?

Banks (or any other business) can choose who they will and won’t do business with. Unless it’s discrimination on the basis of a [protected characteristic](https://www.gov.uk/discrimination-your-rights), it’s not illegal. Since juridical persons don’t have protected characteristics (apart from nationality) it’s virtually impossible to illegally discriminate against them.